# What is the difference between Fulgore and Spinal auto triples?

Tags: killer-instinct-2013

What is the difference between Fuglores "Triple Auto Double" and Spinals "Ghostly Manual"?

They both work by holding down the button for the 3rd hit and I think they both build a resource for their character. But when Spinal came out I thought this was one of his unique things. I want to know things like differences in frame data and damage, if one is better than the other for any reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these "unique" moves do in fact build resource. Spinal's Ghostly Manual gives him a skull, and <s>Fulgore's auto triple gives a pip of energy</s>. After that... Similarities are gone.

Spinal's ghostly manual is just that, a manual. Spinal can follow up a double with a manual, shown as a skeleton arm punching from the ground, by pressing the same strength as the double after it completes before the linker. Just like any other manual, they deal pretty ok damage, but are much harder to break.

Fulgore's auto triple is a bit different. Fulgore can perform three hits for his auto-double by <s>holding down the button</s> he uses for that double. If the third hit connects without being broken, <strike>Fulgore gains a pip of meter for his Reactor Gauge</strike>. This cannot be done with manuals. It is more damaging than a regular double (as it is another hit), but it is easier to break.

I don't know any frame data as I'm not a high level KI player and only understand core mechanics... sorry. I believe there are ways in-game to get frame data, though. Hope this helps enough!

**EDIT:** [Season 2 update tweaked these moves slightly](http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2014/aug/28/iron-galaxy-showing-killer-instinct-season-2-balance-changes-existing-characters-talk-season-2-details/):

Spinal now receives a skull on a ghostly manual (*green* attacks gives skulls).

Fulgore's new reactor system now makes it so he gets a great boost in reactor speed when landing the auto triple. The auto triple is now activated by pressing the button again, instead of holding it.

Comment: Is it classified as a manual because the timing is different to the  Fulgores 3rd auto?

Comment: @Djorge for Fulgore's, you hold the button down. for Spinal's you press again it with "manual" timing(different for each strength).

Comment: Not sure how important it is, but with the release of Season 2 in September/October I think this question will become out of date due to changes

Comment: @Djorge you are correct, when the changes go live I will update my answer.